# What is a common adjective that expresses a child who excessively tells on his friends to his parents for trivial things?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, adjectives

Bob got pushed by his friends, not a big push. Maybe, his friends were just teasing him. Bob, then, told on his friends to his parents.

In another situation, Bob's friends then kidded him in a funny way. But, Bob exaggerated the situation. And Bob told his parents that his friends made fun of him.

Bob is quite sensitive and excessively tell on his friends to his parents for trivial things.

Some little children are like that.

**Do we have a common adjective for that behavior?**

Comment: I would say that Bob is overindulged or spoiled rotten

Comment: Tattletale, crybaby, snitch (used more for adults), spiteful... look up synonyms

Comment: When I was small, a boy who was always running crying to his mother over e.g. little things that other boys had done to him, or nasty dogs that had barked at him, etc, was called names like 'cissy', 'mummy's boy', and 'milksop'.

Answer (score 2):

There are various *nouns* that might fit.

For telling authority figures about trivial things in order to get others into trouble, you might say they are:

- a snitch
- a tell-tale (or 'tattle-tale' in US English)

For the behaviour of exaggerating, you might say they are:

- an exaggerator
- a fibber (less harsh than 'liar')

If you are looking for an adjective then you might have to get to the root of *why* they are doing this. Are they *petty*, or *vindictive*, perhaps? Or are they *attention-seeking*? To get deeper into psychology, they might have '*victim mentality*'.